# wget failing with 404 File not found

Tags: wget, http, jboss

I have two instances of jboss running on the same server with two different ports. ( 8280 & 10580). I am facing issue while downloading a file using `wget` on Port 10580 , but the file is getting downloaded on the other port.  `wget` is failing with 404 Not found.

```
$ wget server1:10580/version.html
  --2015-12-21 19:57:28--  http://server1:10580/version.html
   Resolving server1... 172.16.3.204
   Connecting to server1|172.16.3.204|:10580... connected.
   HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
    2015-12-21 19:57:28 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

Permission on the file is as follows

```
 $ ls -l /data/jboss/myapp-a/deploy/myapp.war/version.html
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jboss admin 54 Dec 16 11:59 /data/jboss/myapp-a/deploy/myapp.war/version.html
```

Was able to access the same file using another instance of jboss in different location with same permission  .

```
$ wget http://server1:8280/version.html
--2015-12-21 19:58:28--  http://server1:8280/version.html
Resolving server1... 172.16.3.204
Connecting to server1|172.16.3.204|:8280... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 54 [text/html]
Saving to: “version.html”

$ ls -l /data/jboss/myapp-b/deploy/myapp.war/version.html
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jboss admin 54 Dec 16 11:59 /data/jboss/myapp-b/deploy/myapp.war/version.html
```

Any suggestions how to resolve the issue?

Comment: Different port?

Comment: There are two jboss instances and each of them running on different Port ie. one on 8280 and the other on 10580

Comment: Your Q doesn't show that...

Comment: Thanks . I updated my question to reflect this information

Comment: Apparently the two jboss environments are not configured identically, otherwise they would serve the same thing obviously. So check for differences.

Comment: I remain suspicious of your copy/paste information.  Your first wget still has port 8280. See wurtel's point.

Comment: i updated...Not a jboss issue as it is failing for wget command